# In rails whats the best way to get the site that a user came from? I am getting conflicting info

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If i enter a url directly into the address bar of the browser, i get the following results:

```
logger.debug ENV['HTTP_REFERER'] // => 
logger.debug request.referrer    // => /
```

So the first one gives me a blank result which is what I expected but the second gives me the root?  Is this correct?  It seems from the docs (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/AbstractRequest.html#M000478) that they should return the same thing.  And secondly, why does it return the root, if there was no referrer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns the root correctly, as when you "hit" the app, you hit the root first (where routes.rb is), and then get redirected.

I would  say **request.referrer** would be nice if used internaly on your application, to know wher (in the application) the user came from.

Whereas ENV['HTTP_REFERER'] works from a browser perspective, and will give you where the user came from before visiting your page.

Hope this helps you, and is clear enough.

Comment: That would make sense except that it looks like form the documentation that request.referrer is just grabbing ENV['HTTP_REFERER'] so they should be the same.  Or am I reading that wrong?

Comment: Except that you're using the request scope, which deals with that request only.

Comment: ulitmately, what I am trying to do is find out if a user came from another website or from a page within our domain or subdomain.  It appears that using request.referrer would not work for that then since it will always show the root if they came from outside.